# Use some datatype as input for a MapReduce job.

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, chaining

I am working on a set of MapReduce jobs that convert a list of plot summaries into an index of every word mapping to the movieID and how many times it was used.  I have one job that takes the input and creates a linked list of Nodes with the word, the movie it came from, and the number of times.  My second job takes this LinkedList and  uses the word as the key and the movieID and number of occurrences as the value and spits out an index of every word mapped to every movie it was used in as well as the number of occurrences.

When calling FileInputFormat.addInputPath() I can either use a Path() or a String with each element separated with a comma.  It wouldn't be hard to just have a massive string with all the data my LinkedList holds but it would be nicer to just have the mapper use the LinkedList as input.

I have read about chaining MapReduce jobs so please don't give me a link to the Yahoo Developer page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two MapReduce jobs (or therefore a LinkedList) here. We can instead treat this as a variant of word count, but with a list of movie IDs added into the output.

**Map input:**

```
354757\tToys come alive
432984\tMore toys
```

**Map code:**

```
String[] idAndWords = input.split("\\t");

for(String word : idAndWords[1].split(" ")) {
    //Do whatever cleansing you want here - remove punctuation, lowercase etc.
    output.write(word,idAndWords[0]);
}
```

**Map output:**

```
("toys","354757")
("come","354757")
("alive","354757")
("more","432984")
("toys","432984")
```

**Reducer code:**

```
//Maps movie IDs to occurrences
Map<String,Int> movieMap = new HashMap<>();
//In here is the list of movie IDs for each word
for(String val : values) {
    if(!movieMap.contains(val)) {
        movieMap.put(val,1);
    } else {
        movieMap.put(val,movieMap.get(val)+1);
    }
}
output.write(NullWritable.get(),key+"\t"+movieMap);
```

**Reducer output:**

```
toys\t[(3547571),(432984,1)]
come\t[(354757,1)]
alive\t[(354757,1)]
more\t[(432984,1)]
```

Now you have no need for a custom `Writable`, and it's fewer than a dozen lines of logic as opposed to what I think would be a pretty complex set of two chained MR jobs.

**Efficiency extension:**

You could make it more efficient by adding a count into the mapper output - with the current implementation then the plotline "dog eat dog" would result in the map output:

```
("dog","354757")
("eat","354757")
("dog","354757")
```

whereas you could reduce it to two records by adding a counter and scanning the whole line before outputting:

```
("dog","354757\t2")
("eat","354757\t1")
```

I didn't want to make my example more complex and less-readable by including this, but it should be trivial to implement and should give good performance savings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but for my problem I have to count the number of occurrences of a word for each different plot summary.  For example:  if I have a plot summary "489373   the quick brown for jumps over a cow" and"838399 the slow brown turtle bit a cow"  an example of the output would be "cow \t 489373 1,838399 1,"

Comment: Well you weren't at all clear on that in the description, which is frustrating as I put a lot of effort into my answer. I have written the correct answer for the question asked. It's still only a small change to my example to get it working for you, and still doesn't require multiple MR jobs or custom Writables. It's just a small change to the reducer logic.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.  So to modify it, when the reducer adds all the movieID's to moviesList there would be duplicates which would mean the word occured multiple times in the plot summary. So I would just have to go through and simplify the moviesList.

Comment: I've updated my answer now to be correct - it uses a HashMap to keep track of occurrences per movie.

Comment: Thank you!  If I had enough reputation I would up vote.

Comment: No worries, it's nice to be able to solve an interesting problem, especially if it saves you three weeks of trying to make a custom Writable and chain jobs ha.

Comment: Yeah.  I figured out that you can add input to a mapper by a Path or by a string and so what I was trying was just having a massive String with all my data in it then the 2nd MapReduce dealing with it.  Needless to say your solution is much better.

Comment: Now just some formatting and it will be perfect!  A little bit of the of the output:
agca {4954684=1}

agd {24709707=1}

age {5905476=1, 2991187=1, 26494309=1, 1228937=1, 2654324=1, 1425905=1, 302970=1, 18933002=1, 25951555=1, 149928=3, 23228817=1, 5352769=1, 20904516=1, 22311056=1, 32568176=2, 1105278=1, 19752996=1, 264103=1, 9362805=1, 16428005=1, 10328139=1, 3653924=1, 12135314=1, 6005212=1, 21084819=1, 24367532=1, 5671546=1, 31477910=1, 14359816=1, 29367699=1, 25524699=1, 9613149=1,